# 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

i have no clue why i get this error last time i did it was because i didn't initiate pygame, but i did this time so i really dont know what the error is

now i get this prntscr.com/8rumj5
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("test")


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

x = 0
y = 0
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)
gray = (153,153,153)

Player = pygame.image.load("player.png")


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player:

    def __init__(self ,x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 32
        self.height = 32


    def render(self,screen):
        screen.blit(Player)






def gameloop():
    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()



screen.fill(white)







player.render(screen)
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)


gameloop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
player.render(screen(100,100))
```

but `screen` is a `Surface`. The `render` function of the `player` class takes a single argument, so you probably want to call

```
player.render(screen)
```

But this would only work if `player` is an instance of the `player` class. You should follow the naming convention and name the class `Player` to avoid confusion and errors, then create an instace of this class with

```
# create instance
player = Player(100, 100)

...other stuff...

# call render
player.render(screen)
```

Comment: @GeeZillion Because in this context, `player` is a class. You should create an instance of it first. Hence rename it to `Player` and create an instace of it with `player = Player(100, 100)`. Then `player` will be an instance of the `Player` class and `player.render(screen)` will work.

Comment: i changed it so player is not on its own file because i had issues ill update my code